# Escape a value in .map() in JSX of react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to iterate over some values of an Object using `.map()`. I need to escape a value. My code is like below

```
let modalrows = Object.keys(this.props.element).map((item,index) => (
  if(item !== 'id') {  //I am getting error in this line
    <tr key={index}>
       <td className="ui header data_type">
            {item === 'name'? 'Name':null}
       </td>
       <td>{this.props.element[item]} <span>Edit</span></td>
    </tr>
  }
));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a bracets to start a code block. Right now you try to use `if` in a return expression. Fixed with braces:

```
let modalrows = Object.keys(this.props.element).map((item, index) => {
  if (item !== "id") {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td className="ui header data_type">
          {item === "name" ? "Name" : null}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.element[item]} <span>Edit</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `filter` to first filter out unnecessary elements:

```
let modalrows = Object.keys(this.props.element)
  .filter(item => item !== "id")
  .map((item, index) => (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td className="ui header data_type">{item === "name" ? "Name" : null}</td>
      <td>
        {this.props.element[item]} <span>Edit</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));
```